# Структура front-end и back-end на разных серверах

Tags: django, frontend, django-rest-framework, backend

Лучшая ли практика иметь front-end и back-end на разных серверах? 
Какие в этом плюсы и какие минусы? 
Я хочу создать веб-приложение с такой структурой, собираюсь использовать Django REST + react.js.
Объясните пожалуйста подробно что должно быть на одном и на другом сервере.
Есть пустой vds на linux, там должен быть nginx, django, rest_framework? Что в таком случае должно быть на стороне front-end и как должно быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Как то писали подобное, правда на фронте был vue.js проект был не большой(магазин с несколькими товарами) и показал себя в полне достойно,на одном были nginx, гуникорн и бд, на втором реализуешь сам фронт, взаимодейтсвие осуществляется по  Апи но так же слышал что при больших запросах (когда поступают часты запросы на другой сервер за фронтом) могут возникать просадки, которые тоже в принципе можно пофиксить, вот тут пример фронта который должен быть на другом серве https://github.com/SteinOveHelset/djackets_vue